# jquery datepicker opening issue after validation

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i have a problem with my jquery datepicker that gets opened automatically when there's a
validation error on the daptepicker field.
here's the code

```
a("#da-ex-validate1").validate(
{

rules:{"jourferie.nombrejours":{required:true,digits:true,max:40},
       "jourferie.date":{required:true,date:true},
       "jourferie.occasion":{required:true}
       },
invalidHandler:function(e,c){var f=c.numberOfInvalids();if(f){var d=f==1?"Vous avez manqué 1 champ.  Il a été mis en évidence":"Vous avez manqué "+f+" champs. Ils ont été mis en évidence";a("#da-ex-val1-error").html(d).show();}else{a("#da-ex-val1-error").hide();}}

});

a("#da-ex-datepicker").datepicker({showOtherMonths:true,onSelect: function() { a(this).valid(); }});
```

so what i want is to disable this behavior.
thanks.

Comment: I guess its because when validation happens than the relevant textbox get focused and datepicker get shown.

Comment: i agree with you,so is there anyway to circumvent this behaviour when validating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the datepicker in "invalidHandler" handler callback.

**Example :**

```
a("#da-ex-validate1").validate(
{
   //exisiting rules 
   invalidHandler:function(e,c){
        // exisiting stuff
        a("#da-ex-datepicker").datepicker("hide");
   }
});
```

Alternately you can set the "focusInvalid" option to false to prevent focusing of invalid elements.

```
a("#da-ex-validate1").validate(
{
   focusInvalid : false,
   //exisiting stuff 
});
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: it didn't work for me in "invalidHandler" but when i use disbale instead of hide it worked but my datepicker doesn't get showed at all after that.

Comment: the `focusInvalid` option, where do I set that? Can I set that on perticular field?